# How to set this particular firebase firestore rule

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i have this firestore rule:
I have a number of users. Each user has a "role" value. 
I want all documents in /users to be read-writable from every user that has role == 3.

I tried:

```
match /users{
        allow read,write: if get(databases/$(database)/users/$(request.auth.uid).role) == 3
    }
```

But it's not working. I can't figure out how to set it

Answer (score 0):

Your rules need to match documents.  If you want to apply the same rule to all documents in a collection, you will need to add a wildcard to the match.  Note the `{uid}` wildcard:

```
match /users/{uid} {
  allow read,write: if get(databases/$(database)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 3;
}
```

Comment: mismatched input '$' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}

Comment: You also had a parenthesis in the wrong place, a missing `data` property, and a missing semicolon

Comment: So how should it be?

Comment: Still getting the same error. I probably have to specify that the database is not realtime but firestore.